# SQL Duplicate Rows Based on Second Field

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with four columns. When there is a duplicate starttime value, I need to show the row that has the latest (newest) insertts value. In the sample below the first two rows have the same starttime value. I would want to show the row that has the insertts value of '2016-02-07 10:45:00' because it has the later (newer) date and time of the duplicate rows. I need this for the entire table not just one row. Thank you in advance. I'm really stuck.

[image: Table Image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It's generally preferable to show text over images for data - and a good idea to show what query(ies) you've attempted so far.

Comment: use [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: Oh. Sorry about that. I've only ever asked one other question in the past. I don't have to do SQL very much and am stuck. I could find the things I've already tried and paste them in here if that would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ROW_NUMBER is probably the easiest way to do this.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DriverID,StartTime ORDER BY InsertTS DESC) RowNum
         FROM   MyTable
        ) t
WHERE   RowNum = 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92f323/1)

Comment: This would work too, but I'd be curious about how it would compare against the self join option.  Probably about the same

Comment: I haven't tried your specific example above yet. I will in a minute. But I tried something that was similar and what was happening is I was losing the row when a duplicate didn't exist. It's like that row wasn't included.

Comment: Add `Activity` to the `PARTITION BY` clause.

Comment: if for any reason, you can have the same Activity for the same StartTime you will need to add Activty to the `PARTITION BY`

Comment: I'm trying it out now. Sorry. I have to get someone to log me in to SQL.

Comment: Ok guys. Without adding in the Activity it seems to be showing my lone non-duplicated values. This looks like it will work. Thanks to both of you for the help. It's a huge time saver!

Comment: Sorry I reread the activity comment more carefully. I understand what you mean Dan. I will add it in there.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT DriverID
      ,Activity
      ,StartTime
      ,MAX(InsertTS) as InsertTS
      ,MAX(Duration) as Duration
FROM TableName
GROUP BY DriverID, Activity, StartTime
```

This assumes that duration will be longer when there are duplicates.  If that's not the case, you might use this as a self join:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM TableName t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DriverID
          ,Activity
          ,StartTime
          ,MAX(InsertTS) as InsertTS
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY DriverID, Activity, StartTime) t2
ON t1.DriverID = t2.DriverID 
   AND t1.Activity = t2.Activity 
   AND t1.StartTime = t2.StartTime 
   AND t1.InsertTS = t2.InsertTS
```

Comment: I tried the first query and it looks like it works. My next question was going to be what to do when the duration is greater in the first row (although it shouldn't ever be). Going to try the second query now.

Comment: I'd probably go with @JamieD77's suggestion in that case instead.  But either one should work.

Answer (score 0):

A [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and [Windowed functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) can make this much cleaner.

```
WITH [Expanded] AS (
    SELECT 
        DriverID
        ,Activity
        ,StartTime
        ,InsertTS
        ,Duration
        ,MAX(InsertTS) OVER (PARTITION BY DriverID, Activity, StartTime) as InsertTS_Max
        ,MAX(Duration) OVER (PARTITION BY DriverID, Activity, StartTime) as Duration_Max
    FROM TableName
)
    SELECT *
    FROM [Expanded]
    WHERE
        InsertTS = InsertTS_Max
```

Comment: As a note if you have multiple records with the same `MAX` value that you want to filter on the `ROW_NUMBER()` or do a `MAX` on the primary key ordered by the time.